# Warum wurden die Farben der Links geändert?

Tags: discussion

Warum wurden die Farben der Links geändert?

Sämtliche Links sind seit heute orange. Warum ist das so?
Kann man bitte wieder zum alten Layout zurückkehren? Die neue Farbe wirkt - zumindest auf mich - wesentlich aggressiver und aufdringlicher als die alte Farbe. Die hat so etwas marktschreierisches und auch etwas kindisches an sich. Das frühere Layout hat auf mich ruhiger, reifer und vor allem seriöser gewirkt.

Ich empfinde dieses Orange als sehr unsympathisch und ich fühle mich damit sehr unwohl. Ich kenne auch sonst keine Seite, wo man diese Farbe für Links gewählt hat. Vermutlich aus gutem Grund.

---

Edit:

Im selben Augenblick in dem ich diese Frage gepostet habe, wurden die alten Farben wiedergestellt. Bastelt da jemand in der Echt-Version von German-Stackexchange am Layout herum? Oder was ist hier los?

Comment: Ich habe auf das "Warum" keine Antwort. Aber das ist vermutlich auch nicht der Kern deiner Frage. Falls dir das Orange wirklich zu arg ist, gibt es Browser-Plugins, mit denen man das CSS für eine Webseite verändern kann. Man findet das, wenn man `custom css {NAME DES BROWSERS} plugin` sucht.

Comment: Auch keine Antwort, nur eine Beobachtung: trat in meiner Erinnerung auch auf anderen SE-Seiten auf ("Die spinnen wohl?"); und änderte sich auf der beobachteten Seite auch _ohne_ reload (einfach Text selektieren, deselektieren). Sofern wir nicht identisches Equipment nutzen: ja, da wird wohl gebastelt (hab den Spaß nicht analysiert)?